# why is proxy code Generated by svctuil so small?

Tags: .net, schema, svcutil.exe, ogc

I'm using svcutil to generate proxy code for the following [web service endpoint](http://geoss.compusult.net/wes/serviceManagerCSW/csw?request=GetCapabilities&service=CSW) which follows the [OGC CSW 2.0.2 (07-006r1)](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/specifications/catalog) standard for catalog services.

I've downloaded the [entire OGC schema files](http://schemas.opengis.net/SCHEMAS_OPENGIS_NET.zip) and placed them into my "D:/temp/OGCSchemas/" Directory.

The schema i'm interested in is CSW, however CSW schema includes and imports other schemas and that's why i've downloaded the entire set.

My question is: Why is the proxy code that is generated so small? I can't use that, can it? Was the code generation interrupted by the error/warning i'm getting?

This is my svcutil excecution:

```
C:\Windows\system32>svcutil D:\temp\OGCSchemas\csw\2.0.2\http-binding.wsdl D:\temp\OGCSchemas\csw\2.0.2\xml-interfaces.wsdl D:\tem
p\OGCSchemas\csw\2.0.2\responses.wsdl D:\temp\OGCSchemas\csw\2.0.2\CSW-discovery.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\csw\2.0.2\CSW-publication.
xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\ows\1.0.0\owsExceptionReport.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\csw\2.0.2\record.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\ows\1.0.0\owsAl
l.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\filter\1.1.0\filter.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\csw\2.0.2\rec-dcterms.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\csw\2.0.2\rec-dcm
es.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\ows\1.0.0\owsGetCapabilities.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\filter\1.1.0\expr.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\filter\1.1.
0\sort.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\filter\1.1.0\filterCapabilities.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\gml\3.1.1\base\geometryAggregates.xsd D:\temp
\OGCSchemas\ows\1.0.0\owsServiceIdentification.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\ows\1.0.0\owsServiceProvider.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\ows\1.0.
0\owsOperationsMetadata.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\gml\3.1.1\base\geometryPrimitives.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\ows\1.0.0\owsDataIdentific
ation.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\ows\1.0.0\ows19115subset.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\ows\1.0.0\owsCommon.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\gml\3.1.1\
base\geometryBasic2d.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\gml\3.1.1\base\geometryBasic0d1d.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\gml\3.1.1\base\measures.xsd D:
\temp\OGCSchemas\gml\3.1.1\base\units.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\gml\3.1.1\base\dictionary.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\gml\3.1.1\base\gmlBa
se.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\gml\3.1.1\base\basicTypes.xsd D:\temp\OGCSchemas\xlink\1.0.0\xlinks.xsd /out:D:\temp\ogc.csw.proxy.cs
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: The required WSDL extension element 'binding' from namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/' was not handled.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2/http']/wsdl:binding[@name='csw-PO
ST']


Generating files...
D:\temp\ogc.csw.proxy.cs
```

And this is the ogc.csw.proxy.cs proxy file it's generating. (VERY SMALL)

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.ContractNamespaceAttribute("http://www.opengis.net/ows", ClrNamespace="www.opengis.net.ows")]

namespace www.opengis.net.ows
{
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaProviderAttribute("ExportSchema")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(IsNullable=false)]
    public partial class ExceptionReport : object, System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable
    {

        private System.Xml.XmlNode[] nodesField;

        private static System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName typeName = new System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName("ExceptionReport", "http://www.opengis.net/ows");

        public System.Xml.XmlNode[] Nodes
        {
            get
            {
                return this.nodesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.nodesField = value;
            }
        }

        public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
        {
            this.nodesField = System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableServices.ReadNodes(reader);
        }

        public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
        {
            System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableServices.WriteNodes(writer, this.Nodes);
        }

        public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public static System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName ExportSchema(System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet schemas)
        {
            System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlSerializableServices.AddDefaultSchema(schemas, typeName);
            return typeName;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT #1**
After reading [Yaron Naveh's blog](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/2009_02_01_archive.html) i realized svcutil does not like this http-binding (i guess the way the OGC has it specified). So i replaced the http-binding.wsdl for the soap-binding.wsdl and everything works without errors and a HUGE proxy file is generate as expected.

Comment: It seems one of your XSD's has errors.

Comment: @S M: Do you know how i can determine which one?

Comment: `XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2/http']/wsdl:binding[@name='csw-POST']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. My WSDL contained no XSD imports and had 3 bindings: Http, Soap11 and Soap12. Removing the HttpBinding solved the problem.

Aditionally, using the XmlSerialized didn't help.